# how to display foreach xslt output in desired sequence?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a input xml as :

```
<Fees>
 <Fee>
    <Name>A</Name>
    <Amt>10</Name>
 </Fee>
 <Fee>
    <Name>B</Name>
    <Amt>20</Name>
 </Fee>
 <Fee>
    <Name>C</Name>
    <Amt>30</Name>
 </Fee>
 <Fee>
    <Name>D</Name>
    <Amt>40</Name>
 </Fee>
</Fees>
```

using xslt :

```
<xsl:for-each select="Fees/Fee">
 <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
 <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
 <xsl:value-of select="Fee"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

When printing names using simple foreach i get output in sequence as :

```
A : 10
B : 20
C : 30
D : 40
```

But i need my output to be in sequence like :

```
C : 30
B : 20
D : 40
A : 10
```

This sequence may change in some regular intervals. Kindly suggest how it can be done from xslt ? If i can specify any sequence in for-each using any template, saying like passing C,B,D,A or any other so it follows same sequence while generating output ?

Comment: `<Amt>10</Name>` is not valid XML. And `<xsl:value-of select="Fee"/>` does not select `Amt`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:param name="order" select="'C,B,D,A'"/>

<xsl:template match="/Fees">
    <xsl:for-each select="Fee">
        <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before(concat(',', $order, ','), concat(',', Name, ',')))" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
        <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Amt"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This allows you to change the order by passing a different string as the `order` parameter.